# How to use wso2 ESB rules mediator

Tags: wso2, drools, esb, rules, wso2-esb

I try to use the WSO2 rules mediator using a simple string as input fact. I looked at example 600, but the difference in my situation is that I want to use a property (previously created by dblookup) as input. Whatever I try, I do not seem to get my input value into the drools rules.
Does somebody have a working example?

Kind regards,
Jeroen van Veldhuizen
Cale Netherlands BV

Comment: Whatever you try: I just can't guess that. So, whatever you try, it might be right, might be wrong, we'll never know. - The rule in Sample 600 is ok, and if it is run in a native Drools session, it works. The String can be inserted by another rule or by code in the embedding Java application - no matter.

Comment: The example gets its input from the soapbody. I want to get the input (in ESB) from a property (using get-property('propname') ). This, I cannot make to work. Maybe it is only possible to extract fact data from the soap xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I have solved this by using the enrich mediator to add the data to the soap message.